# Extract and concat type of specific field from a union type

Tags: typescript

I've got a union type

```
export type DataSourceOptions = MysqlConnectionOptions | PostgresConnectionOptions
```

For simplicity I shortened it, because it unites more types.

Each of these interfaces (MysqlConnectionOptions | PostgresConnectionOptions) has the `type` field.

For example:

```
interface MysqlConnectionOptions {
    readonly type: "mysql" | "mariadb";
}

interface PostgresConnectionOptions {
    readonly type: "postgres",
}
```

I need to extract the values of the type fields on all these types into a separate type which is `"mysql" | "mariadb" | "postgres"`.

There should be some way of doing this trick with the metatypes.

Comment: Why not just `DataSourceOptions['type']`?

Comment: @wonderflame Hmmmm...good point. I tried passing `DataSourceOptions.type` to the config `get` function `config.get<DataSourceOptions.type>`, it threw an error, but actually what you suggest works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html):

```
// type Value = "mysql" | "mariadb" | "postgres
type Value = DataSourceOptions['type']
```

Alternatively, if you are interested in the approach with the built-in [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) utility type, we can get the pick the key that we need (in our case it is `type`) and then using indexed access get the value:

```
// type Value = "mysql" | "mariadb" | "postgres
type Value = Pick<DataSourceOptions, 'type'>['type']
```

This is really redundant, but it becomes a bit better by adding a utility type that will return the union of all values in the object:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]
```

Since we get only the key in the `Pick` we will result in the union of values of the `type` field:

```
// type Value = "mysql" | "mariadb" | "postgres
type Value = ValueOf<Pick<DataSourceOptions, 'type'>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the types of sub-properties using bracket notation, like in value-level code.
This suggests the naive approach:

```js
export type DataSourceTypes = MysqlConnectionOptions['type'] | PostgresConnectionOptions['type']
```

This works, but is clunky and repetitive, with the access being repeated for every element.

However, TypeScript has nifty trick: you can do property access directly over a union; the result is the union of the relevant types.

```js
interface MysqlConnectionOptions {
  readonly type: "mysql" | "mariadb";
}

interface PostgresConnectionOptions {
  readonly type: "postgres";
}

export type DataSourceOptions = MysqlConnectionOptions | PostgresConnectionOptions

export type DataSourceType = DataSourceOptions['type']
//          ^? "mysql" | "mariadb" | "postgres"
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DOBHANgYQHsQQIExhiB5ABwuM2QG8AoZZKCOAE2N3WRh0NCAC5kAIgC2WPBOQAfSVLhRgPAEYSA3CwC+LFqEixEKAAqFMYAOadMREmXohaLxq3acefAUJHiEjRWtvYSADT6hhAAHsFQYILCKAAicGBwAMqEAK5QSG6UIIwAvGiyBMSk5EWFDIrIltZ2EA5VzrV0RZjRcYQJSSLIaRnZeUgAKsnIZSNZufkQdcUA2gDk-hBrALosAPR77EfHyAB6APxAA)

Edit: I see now that @wonderflame suggested this.

Comment: Whoops! I did it in a TS playground on my phone, so couldn't copy-paste and had to retype, missing that in the process. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use bracket notation to reference the interface key

```js
export type DataSourceOptions = MysqlConnectionOptions['type'] | PostgresConnectionOptions['type']
```

`DataSourceOptions` is of type `'mysql' | 'mariadb' | 'postgres'`

Comment: Is there a less verbose way of doing it, for example with metatypes, like Extract or maybe Pick in a loop? The problem is that there are plenty of subtypes that are united like this and I would not like to use this approach. I tried doing it using extract, but it didn't work out.

Comment: TS can do property access over a union. Define `DataSourceOptions` like before, and then use `type ConnectionTypes = DataSourceOptions['type']`.

Comment: @Alex Sorry - got pulled away. Seems like you got your answer. You can also wrap the interfaces with parenthesis and reference the key the same way: `type DataSourceOptions = (A | B)['type']`

Comment: @chazsolo no prob, thanks for the reply anyway!